# OkObjectResult not return the JSON, only the object - Azure Functions and C#

Tags: c#, azure

I have the following Azure Functions API.

I want to output the result of `accessabilityResult`, however it is returning:
`Successfully executed Microsoft.Omex.Bulk.Accessibility.Logging.AccessibilityErrorOutput`

How can I include an OkResponse 200, with the text " Successfully executed " and the JSON result of accessabilityResult?

Azure Function API:

```
public class AccCheckerForOpenXML
{
    private readonly ILogger<AccCheckerForOpenXML> logger;
    public AccCheckerForOpenXML(ILogger<AccCheckerForOpenXML> log) => this.logger = log;
    /// <summary>
    /// Function that receives a httptrigger and then starts processing documents the Office Open XML files.
    /// </summary>
    [FunctionName("AccCheckerForOpenXML")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "docName" })]
    [OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **Name** parameter")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("AccCheckerForDocx: Run method:HTTP trigger --  function processed a request.");
        string filePath = req.Query["name"];
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        filePath ??= data?.name;
        

        // Http Response
        if (filePath == null)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Did not execute. Please include the file path");
        }

        else
        {
            var accessabilityResult = await DocumentProcessor.ProcessDocumentMainAsync(filePath, this.logger); //System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            return new OkObjectResult($"Successfully  executed {accessabilityResult}");
            //return (IActionResult)accessabilityResult;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You get to decide *one* response. Do you want it to be the JSON, or the text message? Why not include a description within the JSON?

Comment: How does the client know the HTTP response if I don't define it with and OkObject or BadObject? Will the client still get an HTTP code? 

So, if I want the text message "HttpMessage". 

Would I just include a property in my list "Success Message" 
``` public string HttpMessage= "Successfully executed" ```

Comment: What do you mean by "how does the client know the HTTP response"? You send it, one way or another. And yes, you could include a description in your JSON, but it would need to be a *property* rather than a *field*. It's still part of the JSON though, not in a separate HTTP header etc. I really think you should consider what *exactly* you want the HTTP response to look like, i.e. what you want to come across the network - status code, headers, body.

Comment: Note that `OkObjectResult` returns a status code 200, whereas `BadRequestObjectResult` returns 400, so the client can tell that way. I would advise you to create a metadata class and return the same outer metadata object either way, something like `new OkObjectResult(new MetaData {Message = Successfully  executed", Result = accessabilityResult})`